# Conditional Style with 3 choices

Tags: javascript

Currently using true or false, but i need a 3rd option.

```
          style = { answer2 ? { backgroundColor: 'green' } : { backgroundColor: 'red' }}
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: nested ternary?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `switch` might make for the best comprehension. You could, for example, create a function that returns a colour based on the condition.

```js
function getColor(condition) {
  switch(condition) {
    case 0: return 'green';
    case 1: return 'red';
    default: return 'blue';
  }
};

document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((el, i) => {
  el.style.backgroundColor = getColor(i);
});
```

```html
<div>One</div>
<div>Two</div>
<div>Three</div>
<div>Four</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the best readability, use if/elseif/else

```
let style;
if (condition1) {
  style = { backgroundColor: 'green' };
} else if (condition2) {
  style = { backgroundColor: 'red' }
} else {
  style = { backgroundColor: 'blue' };
}
```

If you or your team have a high tolerance for nested ternaries, they are an option too. It's basically just doing the same thing you're already doing, but twice.

```
style = condition1
  ? { backgroundColor: "green" }
  : condition2
  ? { backgroundColor: "red" }
  : { backgroundColor: "blue" };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use almost the same syntax as the one you wrote:

```
   style = { answer2 ? { backgroundColor: 'green' } : 
(answer3 ? {backgroundColor:'blue'} :  { backgroundColor: 'red' })}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested ternary operator, and set the background color to red, green, or blue instead of the whole object.

```
const style = {
  backgroundColor: answer2 ? 'green' : condition2 ? 'red' : 'blue',
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you don't work with just booleans is a function like this. It tries to find a color for your given key and provides a fallback if it does not exist.

So if your `answer2` for example is `foo` then it will return `{ backgroundColor: 'red' }` for you.

```js
const getBgColor = (answer) => {
  const answers = {
    foo: { backgroundColor: 'red' },
    bar: { backgroundColor: 'green' },
    baz: { backgroundColor: 'blue' },
  };
  
  // Return chosen color or orange if the answer doesn't exist
  return answers?.[answer] || { backgroundColor: 'orange' };
}

const style1 = getBgColor('foo');
const style2 = getBgColor('bar');
const style3 = getBgColor('baz');
const style4 = getBgColor('i do not exist');

console.log(style1, style2, style3, style4);
```

Comment: It is definitely awesome but it doesn't suite my purpose, but im gonna definitely save this answer for the future me :D

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a function:

```
style = { getBgColor() }

const getBgColor = () => {
   if (condition1) return { backgroundColor: 'green' };
   else return  { backgroundColor: 'red' };
}
```